# Zend DB with Postgres problems with nextval()

Tags: php, zend-framework, postgresql, zend-db, nextval

Ok this is a 2 part question, first primary concern is the `nextval()` bit. I have a table where one of the columns is an auto incrementing column. Being fairly new to postgres and Zend DB I am running into trouble. Inserting a new row on to a table.

This is what i have thus far (and in the CLI this works). But not in the Zend DB stuff..

```
class Comments extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{

    protected $_name = 'comments';

    public function setComment($comment_id = null, $id = null, $comment = null)
    {
        if(($comment_id == null)||(empty($comment_id))||(trim($comment_id) == '')){return false;}
        if(($id == null)||(empty($id))||(trim($id) == '')){return false;}
        if(($comment == null)||(empty($comment))||(trim($comment) == '')){return false;}

        echo 'check one';

        $db = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter();
        if($comment_id == "none")
        {
            $created = time()*1000;
            $data = array(
                        "comment_id" => nextval('comments_comment_id_seq'),
                        "comment" => $comment,
                        "comment_level" => 1,
                        "is_active" => true,
                        "status" => 0,
                        "id" => $id,
                        "user_id" => $_SESSION['role']['user_id'],
                        "ts_create" => $created,
                        "ts_mod" => $created
                    );
            $table->insert($data);
            return true;
        }

    }
}
```

The Error I am getting is:

> **Fatal error**:  Call to undefined function nextval() in
>   **/home/src/branches/portal/application/model/Comments.php**
>   on line **45**

So Not really sure how to adjust for that. I am more familiar with mySQL where I could just drop `NULL` and it would auto increment. So all in all the big problem is the nextval, does Zend DB have anything in the framework that I can fix this issue with?

Next part, since this is a two part question. By using `$table->insert($data);` is that going to automatically use the `$_name` variable? I read through the Zend doc on the subject but its confusing me a bit currently as how to define the right table in the case of an insert.

Comment: There is no php function called `nextval`

Comment: yes I know theres no php function nextval. but with postgres there is.

Comment: so call postgres function, not php's one ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
"comment_id" => new Zend_Db_Expr("nextval('comments_comment_id_seq')"),
```

Comment: ok, so the error I was getting is now gone, I appreciate that. I dunno where you found that but, awesome call. Now I my second part of the question where i was wondering about the insert part seems to be true where thats failing. Any idea on that?

Comment: @chris: what if you try first and see?

Comment: I did, Im getting an error for undefined I am guessing $table is the undefined bit, as I said, the insert/update stuff has me a bit confused with the Zend DB stuff. This is maybe the first time Im seriously taking a crack at using ORM layer for SQL related things. So Im a bit off my game til I understand it better

Comment: @chris: and what is the **actual** error? The guesses is a cool thing, but programmers work with facts

Comment: Yea, I just figured it out, copying from examples and working from them, my variable is `$db` not `$table` and then it looks like I can actually do something like `$db->insert($this->_name, $data)` when I was digging through the examples on the Zend site, it only expressed the $data variable being passed in the insert function.

Comment: overall I just had my first successful insert, now on to the update part. Anyway I thank you for your help.